# apply() use vector to index df rows and cols

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I have a **vector x** that contains indices for the **dataframe y** in the following way:

x[1] is the column index for the dataframe for row 1: **Value 37**

x[2] is the column index for the dataframe for row 2: **Value 110**

etc...

```
> x
[1] 13  5 13  1 13


> y
      1  2   3  4   5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
[1,] 40 49 118 56 110 56 51 47 33 226 33 38 37 41 31 31 31 24 21
[2,] 50 49 118 50 110 51 51 47 32 226 33 35 37 38 31 29 28 27 21
[3,] 50 49 118 50 116 51 42 37 32 224 33 34 35 38 31 26 31 26 22
[4,] 50 53 127 56 116 51 47 47 32 226 35 38 37 41 32 29 32 29 27
[5,] 50 53 127 56 116 56 47 47 36 238 40 42 42 45 38 33 36 30 32
```

I am trying to extract all the corresponding values from my dataframe and put the into a vector (see expected output below).

I could easily do this with two for-loops, but the real dataframe is much bigger and looping would take forever(!), so I am trying to achieve this with the **apply()-family**. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

**Expected Output, is a vector containing the following:**

```
> z
[1] 37 110 35 50 42
```

**Here my data with dput:**

```
#Dataframe y

y <- structure(c(40L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 53L, 53L, 
118L, 118L, 118L, 127L, 127L, 56L, 50L, 50L, 56L, 56L, 110L, 
110L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 56L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 56L, 51L, 51L, 42L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 37L, 47L, 47L, 33L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 36L, 226L, 
226L, 224L, 226L, 238L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 35L, 40L, 38L, 35L, 34L, 
38L, 42L, 37L, 37L, 35L, 37L, 42L, 41L, 38L, 38L, 41L, 45L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 32L, 38L, 31L, 29L, 26L, 29L, 33L, 31L, 28L, 31L, 32L, 
36L, 24L, 27L, 26L, 29L, 30L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 27L, 32L), .Dim = c(5L, 
19L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19")))

#Vector x
x <- c(13, 5, 13, 1, 13)
```

Comment: `y[cbind(1:nrow(y), x)]`? And `y` isn't a `data.frame`. And we have lots of dupes for this around here...

Comment: sry if thats a duplicate, couldnt find anything with my keywords.

Comment: I agree it's hard to think of the correct wording for these dupes. Each has a different title it seems. Also, please be aware that `y` isn't a data frame-  it's a matrix.